# How Do I Reset The A 'Score Bank' In My Program? Python

Tags: python

So I'm trying to add in a scoring system with an external module in a really basic game as I just started Python two days ago.

```
score_history = [0]

a=cur_score()

def var1():
    scoremodule.cur_score()

def initial_score():
    return score[0]

def cur_score():
    return score_history[-1]

def affect_score(delta):
    score_history.append(cur_score() + delta)
    return cur_score()

def reset_score(var1):
    sub=a-a
    print(sub)
```

Here's what I have so far. I just need a way to reset the score with the `reset_score` argument. I can't figure out how to assign `cur_score` a letter or subtract it from its self. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for `score_history = [0]`?  Or maybe `score_history.append(0)`?

Comment: may I ask what ".append" does. I don't remember if I said it, but I just slightly modified something I found online to make this

Comment: As the name suggests, [`.append`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) appends an item to a list.  So `[1, 2].append(3) == [1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want reset_score to do? set a = 0?

```
def reset_score(var1()):
    a=0
```

Comment: what does `var1()` mean as a parameter ?

Comment: Im not sure what the var1 is for, I thought it was an assignable variable but I guess not, and I'm trying to have it set the current score to 0. As when the program loops back, the score stays at whatever it was at

Comment: sorry if I don't make too much sense or sound unknowing, I just started python two days ago

Answer (score 0):

You could use a class to define your methods and then have the score history as an attribute of your class? Is this the result you are after?

```
class Scorer:
    def __init__(self):
        self.score_history = [0]

    def initial_score(self):
        return self.score_history[0]

    def current_score(self):
        return self.score_history[-1]

    def affect_score(self, delta):
        self.score_history.append(self.score_history[-1] + delta)
        return self.current_score()

    def reset_score(self):
        self.score_history = [0]

scoreboard = Scorer()

print(f"Start: {scoreboard.current_score()}")
print(f"add 5: {scoreboard.affect_score(5)}")
print(f"initial: {scoreboard.initial_score()}")
print(f"current: {scoreboard.current_score()}")
scoreboard.reset_score()
print(f"current after reset: {scoreboard.current_score()}")
```

Output

```
Start: 0
add 5: 5
initial: 0
current: 5
current after reset: 0
```

Comment: YES THANK YOU, you are a godsend to new folk like me. Thanks a bunch, sir or maam